# php different html parsing results on local and live server

Tags: php, dom, php-parser

I'm parsing html page. Results are different on local and live server. On local server it displays all information but on live it skips many. Here is my code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

$id = $_GET['video_id'];
$dom = new DOMDocument();

$dom->loadHTMLFile('http://www.ytpak.com/?component=video&task=view&id='.$id);


foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('a') as $link) {
         echo $link->getAttribute('href');
        echo "<br />";

}

?>
```

you can check that code on your local server and here is the url of live server
http://qasimali.byethost8.com/parser.php?video_id=mzhzUnttW44
I'm searching and trying for last 36 hours and I couldn't find out the solution. plz help :)

Comment: What do you mean by `skips many`? Doesn't it work every time you are invoking the script, or does `$dom->getElementsByTagName('a')` not give you all the results required?

Comment: I'm getting links by using getElementsByTagName('a') and on live server it doesn't display all and skip many.

Comment: First thing make sure you parse the same content on both environments. Use file_get_contents() (or similar) to get the HTML page, dump it on screen (or in a file) and check it against what you get on the local server (or in browser when you access the ytpak.com URL).

Comment: An `a` element doesn't require an href attribute. The skipped over entries are the a elements in node list that return an empty string for `getAttribute('href')` since the attribute missing.  Your real question sounds more like "why is external site returning different content from local vs live server?'.

Comment: @axiac I also tried this by using file_get_conents() but results are same(different on live and local)

Comment: @Anthony Yes, if there is problem with getAttribute('href') then it shouldn't parse at localhost but it is working fine at localhost.

Comment: I ran the code on my computer and it produced 33 lines, including empty HREFs. Firefox also found 33 occurrences of the string '<a' in the source code of the remote page. `getAttribute('href')` is working fine, even on @TashenJazbi's live server it returns empty string where appropriate. It seems there is something in (or is missing something from) the request made by the live server that makes the remote server return a different page. Try to `echo(file_get_contents('http://www.ytpak.com/?component=video&task=view&id=mzhzUnttW44'));` instead of parsing. Maybe it returns an error page...

Comment: @axiac you are right. content being displayed through live server are different.Up vote for that. Thank you :)